quantum espresso dipole correction
I am trying to study a two layer structure that contains a ferroelectric layer (PZT) and a second layer that can be an insulator or a metal. I am using a slab configuration with vacuum on each side. For starters I am looking at the PZT slab by itself to try to figure out what to do with the effects of the polarization.
I know that in these cases one must use dipole corrections and in QE there are two ways: the traditional with dipfield=.true. or the new one with assume_isolated='2D'. My study will eventually require an applied field for which I was planning to use assume_isolated='esm' with the esm_bc='bc2' option. But here comes my confusion and question:
Can anyone confirm that the esm option only applies an electric field but does not "enforce" an electric field in the vacuum region. This is only possible by the use of the dipole correction.
Then the question is: let's assume I use the dipole correction to correct the field in vaccum and somehow fix the internal field in the ferroelectric layer, how can I then apply the electric field with esm? These methods seem quite incompatible to me.
Edit1: I need the confirmation about the esm option because from all my tests, when I set the applied field to 0 and perform an scf calculation for the PZT slab fixed in one of the two polarization states, I get a strong electric field in the vacuum region surrounding the slab. I have 10 armstrong of vacuum and the slab is 7 unit cells of thickness which comes out to about 28 armstrons. I am simply wondering at this point if I am using the esm method incorrectly.
